# Modeling Real World Situations / Trigonometric Functions

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-modeling, applications

I got this question and it seemed to be tricky!

You are standing at a base of a Ferris Wheel which is 4 m above ground while your friend is riding. The Ferris Wheel is 8m in diameter. Describe how the shape of the sine curve models the distance your friend is to the platform you are on. Identify the function that will model this situation as well as a function that will model the if we measure his distance to the ground. In your explanation use the following terms:

- Sine=
- Function=
- Radius=
- Repeat=
- Rotate=
- Amplitude=
- Period=
- Intercept=
- Maximum=
- Minimum=
- Axis of the curve=

---

I think that we can model it by using y = a sin (x - d) + c

c is zero here because there is no time

Radius= diameter/2
8/2 = 2
a = 8 which is the amplitude.

Repeat= undefined

Rotate= undefined

*I don't know if it is right or not, just confused. I need some ideas or some keys to solve this situation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to draw a diagram.

**Method 1:**  We define $\theta$ to be the angle formed with the radius that connects the center of the ferris wheel with the point directly beneath it on the platform.

[image: height_of_point_on_ferris_wheel_above_platform]

Then the vertical displacement above the platform is $h = r - r\cos\theta$.  If the angular velocity of the ferris wheel is 
$$\omega = \frac{\theta}{t}$$
then 
$$h(t) = r - r\cos(\omega t)$$
Since a complete revolution is $2\pi$ radians, the period $T$ of the ferris wheel must satisfy the equation
$$2\pi = \omega T$$
from which we obtain
$$T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega}$$

**Method 2:**  We define $\theta$ to be the angle formed with the positive $x$-axis, where the origin is the center of the ferris wheel.

[image]

Then the vertical displacement above the platform is $h = r + r\sin\theta$.  However, we can't simply write 
$$h(t) = r + r\sin(\omega t)$$
unless we assume that the friend starts from the horizontal.  Initially, the friend is at the bottom of the ferris wheel, so $\theta = -\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.  Hence, 
$$h(t) = r + r\sin\left(\omega t - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$
where $\omega$ and $T$ are defined as above.

From here, you should be able to use the given information to complete the problem.

Comment: After checking in and sketching the situation, still not able to solve this issue. I feel that there is something not right. For example, why there is no distance between the ground and the Ferris Wheel? since it is saying that 8m is how far from the ground! to use the information given, it would like that// h(t)= 4 +4sin(wt - π/2 )

Comment: I did not address the second problem.  The first problem was about the height of the ferris wheel relative to the platform, which is $4~\text{m}$ above the ground.  For the second problem, you would have $$h(t) = 8 + 4\sin\left(\omega t - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$ where we add an additional $4~\text{m}$ to account for the distance from the ground to the platform.